# multiple conditions in a case statement duplicates lines in the table

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, case

I'm trying to cluster the clients based on the conditions of the case statement below, everything was going fine until i've added this - AND pbs.pb_plano_assinatura != "Anual"- after that, it duplicates some lines and the value of the column corresponded to this case statement comes null. I know this code is a bit confusing, this just a part of a bigger query, I would love any kind of advice on how to do this kind of operations, this query involves multiple joins so i think I can't turn it into a materialized view. anyway, any help is welcomed. thank you!

```
CASE 
  WHEN ((IF (o.order_created_at < pbs.pb_dt_onboarding, date(pbs.pb_dt_primeiro_onboarding), date(pbs.pb_dt_onboarding))) < date("2021-02-25") AND pbs.pb_plano_assinatura != "Anual") THEN "Mensal Antigo"
  WHEN ((IF (o.order_created_at < pbs.pb_dt_onboarding, date(pbs.pb_dt_primeiro_onboarding), date(pbs.pb_dt_onboarding))) >= date("2021-02-25") and (IF (o.order_created_at < pbs.pb_dt_onboarding, date(pbs.pb_dt_primeiro_onboarding), date(pbs.pb_dt_onboarding))) < date("2021-06-02") AND pbs.pb_plano_assinatura != "Anual") and pb_codigo_promocional is NULL THEN "Mensal Pgto Entrada"
  WHEN ((IF (o.order_created_at < pbs.pb_dt_onboarding, date(pbs.pb_dt_primeiro_onboarding), date(pbs.pb_dt_onboarding))) >= date("2021-06-02") AND pbs.pb_plano_assinatura != "Anual") THEN "Mensal Gratuidade" 
  WHEN ((IF (o.order_created_at < pbs.pb_dt_onboarding, date(pbs.pb_dt_primeiro_onboarding), date(pbs.pb_dt_onboarding))) >= date("2021-02-25") and (IF (o.order_created_at < pbs.pb_dt_onboarding, date(pbs.pb_dt_primeiro_onboarding), date(pbs.pb_dt_onboarding))) < date("2021-06-02") AND pbs.pb_plano_assinatura != "Anual") and pb_codigo_promocional is not NULL THEN "Mensal Cupom"  
  WHEN (pbs.pb_plano_assinatura = "Anual" AND p.value >= 250.0 AND p.status IN('RECEIVED' ,'CONFIRMED', 'RECEIVED_IN_CASH') AND p.originalDueDate = min(p.originalDueDate) over (partition by pbs.pb_id)) OR PBS.pb_id = 'ddcdff35-a044-5ccc-a65d-7e51692b269a' THEN "Anual Entrada" 
  WHEN ((IF (o.order_created_at < pbs.pb_dt_onboarding, date(pbs.pb_dt_primeiro_onboarding), date(pbs.pb_dt_onboarding))) < date("2021-02-25"))AND(pbs.pb_plano_assinatura = "Anual" AND p.value < 250.0 AND p.status IN('RECEIVED' ,'CONFIRMED', 'RECEIVED_IN_CASH') AND p.originalDueDate = min(p.originalDueDate) over (partition by  pbs.pb_id)) THEN "Mensal Antigo"
  WHEN ((IF (o.order_created_at < pbs.pb_dt_onboarding, date(pbs.pb_dt_primeiro_onboarding), date(pbs.pb_dt_onboarding))) >= date("2021-02-25")and (IF (o.order_created_at < pbs.pb_dt_onboarding, date(pbs.pb_dt_primeiro_onboarding), date(pbs.pb_dt_onboarding))) < date("2021-06-02")) and pb_codigo_promocional is NULL AND(pbs.pb_plano_assinatura = "Anual" AND p.value < 250.0 AND p.status IN('RECEIVED' ,'CONFIRMED', 'RECEIVED_IN_CASH') AND p.originalDueDate = min(p.originalDueDate) over (partition by  pbs.pb_id)) THEN "Mensal Pgto Entrada"
  WHEN ((IF (o.order_created_at < pbs.pb_dt_onboarding, date(pbs.pb_dt_primeiro_onboarding), date(pbs.pb_dt_onboarding))) >= date("2021-06-02"))AND(pbs.pb_plano_assinatura = "Anual" AND p.value < 250.0 AND p.status IN('RECEIVED' ,'CONFIRMED', 'RECEIVED_IN_CASH') AND p.originalDueDate = min(p.originalDueDate) over (partition by  pbs.pb_id)) THEN "Mensal Gratuidade"
  WHEN ((IF (o.order_created_at < pbs.pb_dt_onboarding, date(pbs.pb_dt_primeiro_onboarding), date(pbs.pb_dt_onboarding))) >= date("2021-02-25")AND (IF (o.order_created_at < pbs.pb_dt_onboarding, date(pbs.pb_dt_primeiro_onboarding), date(pbs.pb_dt_onboarding))) < date("2021-06-02")) and pb_codigo_promocional is not NULL AND(pbs.pb_plano_assinatura = "Anual" AND p.value < 250.0 AND p.status IN('RECEIVED' ,'CONFIRMED', 'RECEIVED_IN_CASH') AND p.originalDueDate = min(p.originalDueDate) over (partition by  pbs.pb_id)) THEN "Mensal Cupom" 
  END as pb_safra,
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend two steps to clean up the SQL statement. A case statement itself cannot duplicate any line.

## split the case statement into parts

- calculations, which are used several time in this case statement should be set as column values in an inside select statement
- Put a case statement inside the case statement

As a suggestion, please check yourself, since I have no dataset to test.

```
select * except(pb_safra_tmp,Anual,pok,pset,SGorder1,ISminOrginalDueDate) ,
ifnull(pb_safra_tmp ,
    Case when Anual AND not pset AND pok AND ISminOrginalDueDate OR PBS_pb_id = 'ddcdff35-a044-5ccc-a65d-7e51692b269a' 
        THEN "Anual Entrada" end
    )as pb_safra
from(
Select *,
 
CASE 
 WHEN SGorder1 < date("2021-02-25") then 
    Case
        When not Anual THEN "Mensal Antigo"
        When Anual AND pok and pset AND ISminOrginalDueDate THEN "Mensal Antigo"
    end
 WHEN SGorder1 >= date("2021-02-25") and SGorder1 < date("2021-06-02") then
    Case 
        when not Anual then if (pb_codigo_promocional is NULL, "Mensal Pgto Entrada", "Mensal Cupom" )
        when Anual AND pok and pset AND ISminOrginalDueDate THEN if (pb_codigo_promocional is NULL, "Mensal Pgto Entrada", "Mensal Cupom")
    end
 WHEN SGorder1 >= date("2021-06-02") then
    case
        when not Anual THEN "Mensal Gratuidade" 
        when Anual AND pok and pset AND ISminOrginalDueDate THEN "Mensal Gratuidade"
    end
#else null
 END as pb_safra_tmp, 
 
 
  FROM
 (
 SELECT *, pbs.pb_id as pbs_pb_id,
 IF (o.order_created_at < pbs.pb_dt_onboarding, date(pbs.pb_dt_primeiro_onboarding), date(pbs.pb_dt_onboarding)) as SGorder1,
 p.value < 250.0 as pset,
 p.status IN('RECEIVED' ,'CONFIRMED', 'RECEIVED_IN_CASH') as pok,
 pbs.pb_plano_assinatura = "Anual" as Anual,
 p.originalDueDate =  min(p.originalDueDate) over (partition by pbs.pb_id)   as ISminOrginalDueDate
 


from # dummy table
(select current_date() as  originalDueDate, 55 value, 'RECEIVED' status  ) as p cross join 
(select current_date() as order_created_at , 5 pb_codigo_promocional ) as o cross join 
(select current_date() as order_created_at, current_date() as pb_dt_onboarding , current_date() pb_dt_primeiro_onboarding,
 "Anual" pb_plano_assinatura ,  " " pb_id) as PBS

 )
)
```

## UDF - A function to clean up the code

This is the best way to solve these complex case statement. After splitten it in useful parts above, it can now be transformed into a UDF. The select statement is good readable.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION pb_safra(SGorder1 date,Anual bool, PBS_pb_id string)
  RETURNS string
  AS 
  (
    ifnull(
    Case
    WHEN SGorder1 < date("2021-02-25") then 
        Case
        When not Anual THEN "Mensal Antigo"
        When Anual #AND pok and pset AND ISminOrginalDueDate 
            THEN "Mensal Antigo"
        end
    # the other cases ....
    end, 
      case when Anual #AND not pset AND pok AND ISminOrginalDueDate
        or PBS_pb_id = 'ddcdff35-a044-5ccc-a65d-7e51692b269a'  then "Anual Entrada" end  
      )

  )
  ;
   
  SELECT *, 
    pb_safra(
         IF (o.order_created_at < pbs.pb_dt_onboarding, date(pbs.pb_dt_primeiro_onboarding), date(pbs.pb_dt_onboarding)), #SGorder1
         pbs.pb_plano_assinatura = "Anual", # Anual
         PBS.pb_id
 ) as pb_safra
```